# HTML&CSS Не отображается картинка в main

Tags: html, css

проблема заключается в том, что я в css в секции main (и класс тоже main) пишу background-image и т.д, а на сайте не отображается задний фон, вот кусочки кода, где это написано

```
     HTML
<main class="main">

    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="main-tittle">
            Креативное Агенство
        </h1>

        <h2 class="main-subtittle">
            Создание индивидуальных программ развлечений
             на праздниках.
        </h2>

    </div>
</main>
```

==============================

```
      CSS

.main {

background-image: url(/image/bg.jpg);
height: 100vh;}
```

[image: Расположение файлов]

Comment: Вангую, что /images/image.jpg

Comment: Не угадал, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: Не угадал, раз угадывать приходится - подробностей ведь нет. Каково расположение файлов относительно друг друга? Что показывает на элементе в инструментах разработчика? Вам бы эти данные приложить.

Comment: Путь файла в кавычки еще бы вам

Comment: Путь файла взял в кавычки, ничего не изменилось, скрин с расположением файлов прикрепил к основному коду

Comment: Принятый ответ говорит об обратном

Comment: @void да просто слеш в начале пути убрать, кавычки вообще не при делах

Comment: Ну, если index и image в корне лежат, то ./ погоду не делает тоже. Значит, не лежат. Но по вопросу не понять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main {
    background-image: url('./image/bg.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]